# How can I clone a table, parse cells, and replace numbers with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

i have a table on my website. I am using jQuery to clone it and now i like to replace German numbers in the cells to the English format. I try this:

```
 var cln = $('#test').clone();
                    cln.find('td').each(function() {
                      $(this).text($(this).text().replace('.', '').trim()); 
                      $(this).text($(this).text().replace(',', '.').trim());
                      $(this).text($(this).text().replace('VK', '').trim());
                    })
```

My problem. I have some dates in the table that will be replaced also. So i need to check if the cell contains a valid german number and then replace it. I can not select the cols to replace i need to identify a valid german number.

Here is my original table before cloning:

```
<table id="test">
<tr><td>07.05.2023</td><td>4.560,75</td></tr>
<tr><td>4.560,75</td><td>08.05.2023</td></tr>
</table>
```

This must be:

```
<table id="test">
<tr><td>07.05.2023</td><td>4560.75</td></tr>
<tr><td>4560.75</td><td>08.05.2023</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Will the table ever have a number without decimals, or are they always displayed? If they are always included, you could just check for the existence of a `,` in the cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a function and a regexp

```js
const euDateFormat = /^\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}$/;
const euAmountFormat = /^\d{1,3}(\.\d{3})*(,\d{2})$/
var $cln = $('#test').clone();
$cln.find('td').text(function() {
  let text = this.textContent.trim();
  if (euAmountFormat.test(text)) {
    text = text.replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.');
    console.log(text)
  } // no need for else unless you want to change the date too
  return text.replace("VK","");
})
$("#output").html($cln)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody id="test">
    <tr>
      <td>07.05.2023</td>
      <td>4.560,75</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4.560,75</td>
      <td>08.05.2023</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table>
  <tbody id="output">
  </tbody>
</table>
```